# Dotnet app.dll Segmentation Fault CentOS 7

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, centos7

I m to try the execute a app in dotnet core 5, when I wirite **dotnet app.dll** the response is **Segmentation Fault** or **Violación de segmento** (in spanish).
I install the sdk and runtime according to the .net guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-centos
It is the same server, the only difference is the OS previously had debian 9 and it worked perfectly for.
To compiler I use this dotnet publish -c Release -o ./publish-CenOS --runtime centos-x64
for debian I was use dotnet publish -c Release -o ./publish-debian --runtime debian-x64
I do not know why this error does not happen to me in centos
greetings!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by doing a build and publish from the same server that I am trying to run the application.